# If $f_n$ converges in $L^2$ to $f$ and converges almost everywhere to $g$, then $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I$ be a (Possibly unbounded) interval, $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{R}}\subseteq L^2(I)$ such that there exists some function $f\in L^2(I)$ in a way that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}||f_n -f||=0$$

where $$||f_n -f||=\int_{I}(f_n-f)^2.$$

Let's also suppose that there exists some function $g\in L^2(I)$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=g(x)$$
for almost every $x\in I$.

Then $f(x)=g(x)$ for almost every $x\in I$.

---

My try goes like this:

It's enough to prove that $||f-g||=0$. To prove this, we take $\varepsilon>0$, and $N$ such that $||f_n-f||<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for any $n\geq N$. Then

$$||f-g||\leq ||f-f_n||+||f_n-g||<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+||f_n-g||.$$

If I can make $||f_n-g||$ less or equal than some particular expression related to $\varepsilon$, it's over. But since $I$ is an arbitrary interval, I don't see how to do that.

So, does this approach work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence $f_n$ is convergent in $L^2$, therefore we can find $N$ such that 
$||f_n-f_m||<\epsilon$ for all $n,m\geq N$.

Now choose $n\geq N$ and we calculate
\begin{align}\int (f_n-g)^2 &=\int \liminf_m(f_n-f_m)^2\\& \leq  \liminf_m\int(f_n-f_m)^2\\&=\liminf_m||f_n-f_m|| <\epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is very clear. This problem also is sloved by sub-sequence argument.

Comment: Might be simpler to avoid the Cauchy criterion and write

$$\int (f-g)^2 = \int \liminf \,(f-f_n)^2 \le \liminf \int (f-f_n)^2 =0.$$

The inequality there comes from Fatou's Lemma, which might be good to mention.

Comment: @zhw. Actually, that's how I thought of this problem initially. But then I tried to modify this to make OP approach complete. However, this is useful for everyone to see so I am upvoting this comment.

Comment: Thanks. That's really a good way to do it. And yes, I understood the use of Fatou Lemma there.